# How to deserialize my object in Android after passing it using an intent?

Tags: java, android, serialization, casting, serializable

I'm trying to use Serializable to pass an object from one activity to another using the following code:

```
final Event rowItem = (Event) getItem(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("event", rowItem);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This works fine (no errors), so on the other end I want to deserialize it again using:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Event event = (Event) intent.getSerializableExtra("event");
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error saying:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mycomp.model.Event
```

This is the first time I use Serializable to pass an object, so I might do something really stupid. I wouldn't know what however.

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong here? I'd be happy to share more code if needed..

[EDIT]
Turns out I did use `@SerializedName(value = "the_serialized_name")` for every parameter, but I didn't use `implements Serializable` with the class name. Extremely stupid of me. But thanks for answering!

Comment: Share more code with us, but you should't be using Serializable  in android. Instead use Parcelable, have a look at the docs and some code samples, its pretty simple.

Comment: Is your class `Event` implements `Serializable`?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you get a String instead of a Serializable when calling

```
(Event) intent.getSerializableExtra("event");
```

So You could try to print this line to see what value is returned. That might help you figure out what the problem is.

Also, you should have a look at the Parcelable Class, which is a kind of Serializable designed just for android